# npm install git in VSCode

Tags: git, npm, visual-studio-code

Just ran `npm install git` in VSCode terminal and ran `git --version`with this response:

```
git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ git --version
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Had already restarted after installing Node.js and git install.  Please help getting git to work inside VSCode.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what made you think that `npm install git` is the correct way to install git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing git global with -g

```
npm install -g git
```

Or just install git with the official documentation
https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: That's not going to help much, since the npm `git` package is not actually the git command line tool..

Answer (score 3):

`npm install git` doesn't install git (i.e. the command line tool to manipulate git repositories).

It installs the [npm package called git](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git) which seems to be a JavaScript library to interact with git repositories (which makes the name accurate, but still misleading).

npm is not a general-purpose package manager.

Answer (score 1):

1. Windows, macOS and Linux/Unix Installs: https://git-scm.com/downloads and run the installer from your downloads folder.
2. Type "git --version" ,minus the quotes, in the command line.

Here is additional documentation on Gits website for installing Git: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

To install git from npm using your command line use this "npm i git-win" minus the quotes. Here is npm's documentation for installing git from npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-win

Answer (score 1):

first, you have to download and install the git from the below link :

https://git-scm.com/downloads

then use of below codes :

```
npm install git

git init
```